# work around gwt same origin policy

Tags: gwt, same-origin-policy

I have a gwt app that i debug on standard gwt port 8888 that comunicate with a JAX-RS/Jersey/Glassfish service running on port 8080

This is the gwt code:

```
StringBuffer postData = new StringBuffer();

postData.append(URL.encode("username")).append("=").append(URL.encode(user));
postData.append("&");
postData.append(URL.encode("password")).append("=").append(URL.encode(password));

RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, "http://localhost:8888/gestdoc/resources/data/login");
builder.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
try {
    builder.sendRequest(postData.toString(), new RequestCallback() {

          public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) 
          {
              String responseText = response.getText();
              String headers= response.getHeadersAsString();
              String statusText= response.getStatusText();
              int statusCode= response.getStatusCode();
              String toString= response.toString();


              System.out.println("responseText: "+responseText);
              System.out.println("headers: "+headers);
              System.out.println("statusTest: "+statusText);
              System.out.println("statusCode: "+statusCode);
              System.out.println("toString: "+toString);

              GestoreUtenze.this.cddoc.loginResponse(true);
          }


          public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
             // exception handling
          }
        });
} catch (RequestException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is the output:

```
responseText: 
headers: 
statusTest: 
statusCode: 0
toString: com.google.gwt.http.client.Request$1@6c1a82
```

I have a java batch client with i have tested my Jersey services and are ok.

I have read many post and I suppose that I have a SAME ORIGIN POLICY problem.

I have tried many solutions:

1. Run the browser where i debug my gwt app with non Same Origin Policy (chrome and firefox)
2. Add the row    in my gwt config file
3. I have tried to set up a proxy without success. How can I do?

Can you help me to solve this problem please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only usable way I found so fare was starting Google Chrome with

```
--disable-web-security
```

This disables the Same Origin Policy.

You can do this in Win 7 by pressing [Strg + SHift + Right click] --> Properties and add --disable-web-security to the target property. However you should only use this property when debugging!

FF and IE don't seem to have a working way to bypass the SOP policy (couldn't get any of the examples I found online to working and tried at least a week! :/)